# How to find the username in Bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I'm starting out on some Linux bash scripting and I'm trying to get the username so I can `cd` to that user's Desktop:

```
cd /home/$(user I'm currently using)/Desktop
```

The code should be similar to the above to my understanding. What kind of terminal command would return just the name of the user I'm using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command you were looking for is [`whoami`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whoami).

Answer (score 7):

You're probably just looking for `cd ~/Desktop`.

Comment: or `~other/Desktop` for user `other`.

Answer (score 0):

See Here

> [max@localhost ~]$ echo $USER
>
> **max**

**This will print the name of the user who currently logged in the terminal**

> [max@localhost ~]$ su -
>
> Password:
>
> [root@localhost ~]# echo $USER
>
> **root**

Answer (score -1):

`who` is the command for you which is a shortform for `whoami`

Comment: who is not short form for whoami `who` shows who are all logged on the system(means in tty1,tty2 and so on)
`whoami` means who is currently using the system (who is running this command, it always shows your name only because you are running this command, if other person run this command then it will show his name) It always print single name.